# Which type of airfoil does the 737 use?

Tags: aircraft-design, wing, boeing-737, airfoil

NACA airfoils are not used anymore except on some aircraft. So which type of airfoil does the 737 use? Which company designs it and builds it?

Comment: I think Boeing still designs the airfoil.

Comment: Boeing designs and builds them. Why would a large aircraft company not design and build something so fundamental to its planes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Boeing designs its own airfoils for its aricraft. According to [this site,](http://m-selig.ae.illinois.edu/ads/aircraft.html) the following airfoils are used in 737:

Boeing 737-100: Wing root- BAC 449/450/451; Wing tip- BAC 442

Boeing 737-200: Wing root- BAC 449/450/451; Wing tip- BAC 442

Boeing 737-300: Wing root- BAC 449/450/451; Wing tip- BAC 442 mod

Boeing 737-400: Wing root- BAC 449/450/451; Wing tip- BAC 442 mod

Boeing 737-500: Wing root- BAC 449/450/451; Wing tip- BAC 442 mod

The 737 wings are manufactured at the Boeing plant in Renton, Washington.

Comment: How about the tails? Horizontal and vertical.

Comment: Tail sections usually use symmetrical profiles such as the NACA0009 and (slightly thicker) NACA0012. Although the exact airfoil is not specified, [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/48784/29155) confirms those thickness ratios for the Boeing 737-100 as well.

Answer (score 0):

From [this site](http://www.airfoiltools.com/search/index?MAirfoilSearchForm%5BtextSearch%5D=737&MAirfoilSearchForm%5BmaxThickness%5D=&MAirfoilSearchForm%5BminThickness%5D=&MAirfoilSearchForm%5BmaxCamber%5D=&MAirfoilSearchForm%5BminCamber%5D=&MAirfoilSearchForm%5Bgrp%5D=&MAirfoilSearchForm%5Bsort%5D=1&yt0=Search), contains links to the profiles which can be used for Xfoil.
[image]